# What happens if the init container resources are set to BestEffort but the normal container resources are set to be actual values (burstable)?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, cloud, cpu-usage

So I am struggling to understand some details about init-containers in Kubernetes.

In the kubernetes docs we are reading the following - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/:

> The highest of any particular resource request or limit defined on all
> init containers is the effective init request/limit. If any resource
> has no resource limit specified this is considered as the highest
> limit. The Pod's effective request/limit for a resource is the higher
> of:
>
> 1. The sum of all app containers request/limit for a resource
> 2. The effective init request/limit for a resource
>
> Scheduling is done based on effective requests/limits, which means
> init containers can reserve resources for initialization that are not
> used during the life of the Pod. The QoS (quality of service) tier of
> the Pod's effective QoS tier is the QoS tier for init containers and
> app containers alike

Let us say we have the following defined values-wise. These are just to illustrate an example:

```
resources:
  initContainer1:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "0"
        cpu: "0"
      limits:
        memory: "0"
        cpu: "0"
  initContainer2:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "10Mi"
        cpu: "5m"
      limits:
        memory: "20Mi"
        cpu: "50m"
  mainContainer:
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "200m"
```

Then this means, that the **effective init** request/limit becomes

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "0"
    cpu: "0"
  limits:
    memory: "0"
    cpu: "0"
```

So based on the text from the Kubernetes documentation for init containers, in this scenario the pod's Effective Request/limit also **becomes the best effort values**. Please feel free to correct me if I have misunderstood this part or if my understanding is correct.

Yet when I've deployed and described the pod, Ive seen that the main container still gets assigned the set values here even if the init-container resources are set to BestEffort "0".

But I am guessing that the problem with setting Best Effort for an Init Container in Kubernetes, is that you will have no actual idea how much resources (CPU+MEM) that the pod is *actually* using?

Comment: Have you clearified this question? I'm stumbling over the same problem, because the written text in the documentation is not very precise.